# Error on search date sql

Tags: sql

i have this query to get all data between tow date like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM cashier_trans
WHERE cashier_trans_Customerid LIKE '%kam%'
OR cashier_trans_Date
BETWEEN '2012/12/01'
AND '2012/12/02'
ORDER BY cashier_trans_Customerid, cashier_trans_DocType, cashier_trans_DocId ASC
```

the data i retrieve from Database :

```
Name     Date
kam      16/12/2012
```

why i retrieve Date on `16/12/2012`

Comment: `'2012/12/01'` is **not** a Date, it's a character literal. Your SQL relies on implicit data type conversion that might not do what you expect it do do. If you have a standard compliant database you should use a real date literal, e.g. `date '2012-12-01'`. You should also mention which DBMS you are using. Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the where clause condition:

```
WHERE 
     cashier_trans_Customerid LIKE '%kam%'
  OR  <-------------
     cashier_trans_Date BETWEEN '2012/12/01' AND '2012/12/02'
```

The data you show contains Name = 'kam' and therefore satifies the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

'cashier_trans_Date' Column in your table is of format 'mm/dd/yyyy'. But in the query you are using as 'yyyy/mm/dd' format. 
This will help you,

```
SELECT *
FROM cashier_trans
WHERE cashier_trans_Customerid LIKE '%kam%'
OR cashier_trans_Date
BETWEEN '12/01/2012'
AND '12/02/2012';
```

Besides in the 'where' clause you are using like '%kam%'. So obviously you will receive the records of 'kam'

Comment: You are welcome :) may be you can vote my answer if it's useful for you